# Django resend activation link, missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-users, django-request

I have read similar questions but I cannot understand why this is not working. I am trying to send a reactivation email to user when they click on a link. The activation link is generated properly when the user signs up and the email is sent, but when I try to call the same function again to reactivate link, it is not working saying it is missing one parameter. Here's the function:

**acounts/views.py**

```
def sendactivationmail(request, user):
    # Creating token and masing uid of user
    token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
    uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode()
    # Sending email for email verification
    subject = 'Please Verify Your Email'
    from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    to_email = [user.email]
    context = {
        'url': settings.BASE_URL + reverse('user-activation-link', kwargs={
            'uidb64': uid,
            'token': token,
        }),
    }
    contact_message = render_to_string('verify_email.html', context)
    plain_message = strip_tags(contact_message)
    send_mail(subject, plain_message, from_email, to_email, html_message=contact_message, fail_silently=True)

    return redirect(reverse('login'))
```

**accounts/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *
from . import views
from urllib import request
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^reactivate/$', views.sendactivationmail(request, User), name='reactivate'),
```

Is this the right way to pass on the *request* and *user* parameters to the function?

EDIT: This is the link that is used to redirect user:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'reactivate' %}">Click here</a> to resend the activation email.</p>
```

Comment: please post the html where the user is clicking to send activation link

Comment: you are passing User model, from User model get the particular user and then pass that user object as parameter.

Comment: @Exprator I have updated the question with it, but it is a simple link that redirects to reactivate page.

Comment: @VikasP Could you please explain how I can do it? I have tried User.pk() and other objects of User class but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: @NaeemKhan get user object like this , `user = User.objects.get(username="which ever user you want to send")` and pass this user object.

Comment: Is it possible to get the current logged in user?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would send an reactivation link to a logged in user but `user=request.user` would give the logged in user.

Comment: @HenryM I have tried that and it gives: AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'user' error. I have a custom login/signup system, and if the user has not activated their email address, they are shown a page where it says they must validate their email address. In such case, the is_active flag is set to false, and I want them to be able to resend the activation link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your urlpattern to this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^reactivate/$', views.sendactivationmail, name='reactivate'),
    .....
]
```

and html to, but the user has to be logged in to use this link. remember that

```
<p><a href="{% url 'reactivate' request.user %}">Click here</a> to resend the activation email.</p>
```

Comment: That fixed this problem. Thank you so much!